# ifx, macros and grouping

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals

I do not understand how \ifx interacts with macro definitions. Here is a minimal example:

```
\def\a#1{\b}
\def\b#1#2{[#1:#2]}
\a ABC
```

The output is `[B:C]`, as expected. If I change the definition of `\a` to

```
\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else \b\fi}
```

then the output becomes `[:B]C`. Where does the empty argument to `\b` come from, and how do I get rid of it?

I apologize for asking a question that surely has been asked on this site before. I tried hard to find the answer, but in vain. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With

```
\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else \b\fi}
```

the call `\a ABC` takes `A` as the argument to `\a`, so the input stream becomes

```
\ifx EA\else\b\fi BC
```

and, since the condition turns out to be false, what remains in the input stream is

```
\b\fi BC
```

Thus the arguments to `\b` are `#1<-\fi` and `#2<-B`, so we get

```
[\fi:B]C
```

Now `\fi` performs its duty of disappearing and you get

```
[:B]C
```

If instead you define

```
\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else\expandafter\b\fi}
```

after the conditional we get

```
\expandafter\b\fi BC
```

The `\expandafter` makes `\fi` disappear *before* `\b` is expanded, so we find

```
\b BC
```

and finally

```
[B:C]
```

---

In the case of `\a EBC`, the first step would give

```
\ifx EE\else\b\fi BC
```

that turns into

```
\else\b\fi BC
```

The expansion of `\else` throws out everything up to the matching `\fi` and we simply get

```
BC
```

---

Looking at the log file with `\tracingmacros=1` helps:

```
\tracingmacros=1
\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else \b\fi}
\def\b#1#2{[#1:#2]}
\a ABC
```

will produce

```
\a #1->\ifx E#1\else \b \fi 
#1<-A

\b #1#2->[#1:#2]
#1<-\fi 
#2<-B
```

that shows precisely what I diagnosed without doing the experiment.

If you add also `\tracingifs=1` (with an e-TeX based engine such as `pdftex`), you get

```
\a #1->\ifx E#1\else \b \fi 
#1<-A
{vertical mode: \ifx: (level 1) entered on line 4}
{\else: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 4}

\b #1#2->[#1:#2]
#1<-\fi 
#2<-B
{horizontal mode: \fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 4}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am too used programming in conventional languages. It all makes sense now!

Comment: @BorisBukh It takes a while understanding how conditional work in TeX; a true conditional just removes itself, leaving the duty of getting rid of the false branch to `\else`; a false conditional removes itself and anything up to (and including) the matching `\else`.

Answer (score 6):

`\b` grabs the `\fi` but if you use the following definition of `\a`, the you obtain the expected output:

```
\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else \expandafter\b\fi}
```

The above completes the conditional `\if..\fi` before processing `\b`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\a#1{\b}
\def\b#1#2{[#1:#2]}
\a ABC

\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else \b\fi}
\a ABC

\def\a#1{\ifx E#1\else \expandafter\b\fi}
\a ABC

\end{document}​
```

If you wish to see this, use the following definition of `\b` and check your `.log` for the values contained in `\argA` and `\argB`:

```
\def\b#1#2{%
  \def\argA{#1}\show\argA%
  \def\argB{#2}\show\argB%
  [#1:#2]}
```

For the second call to `\a` above, you'll find

```
> \argA: macro
-> \fi .
> \argB: macro
-> B.
```